# How to join two queries for timeseries

Tags: sql

My table is set up like :

```
id .   int(11) PK
key .   char(4) PK
timestamp .   datetime PK
value .   double
```

I record multiple **time series** measurements of IoT sensor data in this table.

For e.g, `key` could be something like `temp` or `humidity`.

Querying for this would be :

`SELECT *  where`id`=496 and key == temp;`
`SELECT *  where`id`=496 and key == humidity;`

Both of these, for the same `id`, line up exactly on `timestamp`.
What is the best way to `combine` (for lack of a better term) the results of these two queries?

Joining data from different tables
https://codeinthehole.com/tips/joining-between-date-and-datetime-fields-in-postgres/

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want both readings returned in the same record, you will probably want to "Self-Join" the table - Join it with itself as shown below:

```
SELECT T1.timestamp, T1.id, T1.key, T1.value, T2.key, T2.value 
FROM Table AS T1
INNER JOIN Table AS T2 ON T2.id = T1.id
WHERE (T1.key LIKE 'temp' AND T2.key LIKE 'humidity')
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  id, timestamp, 
  max(case key when 'temp' then value end) temp, 
  max(case key when 'humidity' then value end) humidity
from tablename
where id = 496 and key in ('temp', 'humidity')
group by id, timestamp
```

I assume that there exist for the same `timestamp` 1 `value` for `key = 'temp'` and 1 `value` for `key =  'humidity'`